# want to hide progressbar which comes on top in navigation bar of MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmoviewcontroller

[image]

Is there any way to hide progress bar which comes on top in navigation bar of MPMoviePlayerController?

I want to hide because I do not want user to forward/backward the video. However, User can exit it by clicking on DONE button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the scrubber is available both in the Embedded and the FullScreen version of the MPMovieControlStyle the only solution I see is to use MPMovieControlStyleNone and overlay your own version of the Done button on top of the Movie playback view.

Comment: so by applying controlstyle to NONE, will it hide entire navigation bar? I want navigation bar, because I am giving url to MPMoviePlayerController, and it gives "loading movie" with loading indicator until it loads movie... So I do not want to hide entire navigation bar.

Comment: The progress bar shows a Done button to its left and a _fullscreen_ button to its right .. so controlstyle set to NONE will hide those and the << and >> controlls at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks, but I need navigationbar as it gives "Loading Movie..." indication on navigationbar so I want it...

Comment: in that case you can hide the controlls (progress bar, ..) by switching the MPMovieControlStyle to MPMovieControlStyleNone as soon as you get notified that the movies starts playing.

Comment: you can not hide only the progress bar by using the standard MPMovieControlStyle options, it is all or nothing ;-)

Comment: Yes, but is there any way to get sub view from navigation bar, and I can get progress bar from that, so I can hide????